# What does assignment of a pointer element to another pointer element in the array mean?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, pointers, assignment-operator

I don't quite understand what does it mean to assign one pointer to another pointer? Here **p is an array of pointers/2D array, then p[0] is assigned to p[1], do both of them point to same address?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void) {
    int i,j;
    int **p = (int **)malloc(2 * sizeof(int *));
    p[0] = (int *)malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
    p[1] = p[0];
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        for(j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            p[i][j] = i + j;
    printf("%d",p[0][0]);
    return 0;
}
```

I expected output to be 0 but it's actually 1, why?

Comment: `p` is an array of pointers. So, you assign the pointer from p[0] to p[1]. So, they both point to **the same** area which is a size of 2 integers. Looks like a mess to me.

Comment: p is not an array (or **p as you said), pointer and array are very different

Answer (score 2):

The both pointers `p[0]` and `p[1]` have the same value after the expression statement

```
p[1] = p[0];
```

So where the expression `p[1]` is used it can be substituted for the expression `p[0]`  because the both expressions have the same value and vice versa.

In this loop

```
for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    for(j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        p[i][j] = i + j;
```

when `i` is equal to `1` and `j` is equal to `0` (given that `p[1]` is the same as `p[0]`.) So `p[1][0]` is equivalent to `p[0][0]` and equal to `i + j` that is `1`.

In fact this loop

```
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        p[i][j] = i + j;
```

is equivalent to the loop

```
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        p[0][j] = i + j;
```

Thus the second iteration of the outer loop rewrites the values stored in `p[0][0]` and `p[0][1]` after the first iteration.

In the second iteration we have `i` is equal `1`. So for `j` in the range [0, 1] we have

```
p[0][0] = i + j (when i == 1 and j == 0 ) = 1
```

and

```
p[0][1] = i + j (when i == 1 and j == 1 ) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

> I don't quite understand what does it mean to assign one pointer to
>   another pointer? Here **p is an array of pointers/2D array, then p[0]
>   is assigned to p[1], do both of them point to same address?

Yes.  But it's probably more useful conceptually to ignore the *significance* of the values of `p[0]` and `p[1]` (that the values are pointers, and what those values point to) to focus instead on the fact that after the assignment, their values are the same.  That the values then point to the same thing follows from that.

Note well that I have intentionally chosen wording that distinguishes between designators for storage locations (e.g. "`p[1]`") and the *contents* of those locations -- their values.  We often use language that blurs the distinction because it's cumbersome to speak precisely in that way, but it is essential that you maintain the distinction in your head.  Formally, it is not the *expression* `p[1]` or even the storage location it designates that is a pointer, but rather the value stored there.  The assignment operator copies that value to another storage location, so naturally, if the contents of that other storage location are interpreted according to the same data type, then they have the same meaning as the original.

> I expected output to be 0 but it's actually 1, why?

Because after having set `p[1] = p[0]`, the expression `p[1][0]` designates the same object that `p[0][0]` does.  After you assign `p[1][0] = 1 + 0`, you can therefore read back the resulting value (1) from either `p[1][0]` or `p[0][0]`.

Answer (score 0):

> do both of them point to same address?

Yes.

Here's a modification of your program which should make this more clear:

```
int main(void) {
    int i,j;
    int **p = (int **)malloc(2 * sizeof(int *));
    p[0] = (int *)malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
    p[1] = p[0];
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        for(j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            p[i][j] = i + j;
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        printf("%d (%p)\t", i, p[i]);
        for(j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            printf("%d ", p[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here we print out the pointer values `p[0]` and `p[1]`, and all four cells of the "two-dimensional" array -- except that, yes, there are really only two cells, doing double duty for each of the two rows.  On my system, this prints out

```
0 (0x7f92ca402710)  1 2 
1 (0x7f92ca402710)  1 2
```

and you can clearly see that the two pointers are the same.

We can think of this, in memory, as looking something like this:

```
   +-------+
p: |   *   |
   +---|---+
       |
       v
   +-------+           +---+---+
   |   *----------+--->| 1 | 2 |
   +-------+     /     +---+---+
   |   *--------'
   +-------+
```

If, on the other hand, you called `malloc` three times, instead of two, like this:

```
    int **p = (int **)malloc(2 * sizeof(int *));
    p[0] = (int *)malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
    p[1] = (int *)malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
```

you would get a printout more like this:

```
0 (0x7fb747402710)  0 1 
1 (0x7fb747402720)  1 2
```

and you would get a picture in memory something like this:

```
   +-------+
p: |   *   |
   +---|---+
       |
       v
   +-------+           +---+---+
   |   *-------------->| 0 | 1 |
   +-------+           +---+---+
   |   *--------.
   +-------+     \     +---+---+
                  '--->| 1 | 2 |
                       +---+---+
```